# Work team sitting at a table question

Tags: permutations

## A question  came up recently:

---

> There is a team sitting at a round table. They all leave the table
> for a lunch break, and after returning to the table, each person finds that
> both their neighbours on the right and on the left do not sit next to
> them anymore. How many people may be sitting around the table?
> Describe all the possibilities.

Personally, I have no idea how to prove this mathematically -- all I know, after trial and error, that 1, 2, 3, and 4 don't work and 5 does. Is there a way I can prove this, and show (if they are) that greater numbers are possible?

Comment: The question boils down to this: is there a Hamiltonian cycle through the complement of the cycle graph of $n$ vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question boils down to this: is there a Hamiltonian cycle through the complement of the cycle graph of n vertices?

For $n < 5$ the answer is obviously no: the complements here are the empty graph for $n = 2$ and $3$, and two separate $K_2$ graphs for $n = 4$.

For $5$, the answer is yes, and there is essentially only one way to do it: if our people are $ABCDE$ around the table originally, $ACEBD$ is the only layout that works.

For $6$ and higher, we can determine the yes-no answer as simply this: is it always true that the $n$th person can push a chair in in a place that isn't next to one of their former neighbors?  And the answer to this is obviously yes: the two neighbors only block off the four spots immediately next to them, and at more than $4$ seats already placed, there are more than $4$ spots to push in a new chair!